# Custom Error Page using global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I have tried to redirect the page if any http error occurs and then redirect to the custom error page using this code.

```
Server.Transfer("~/Error Page/errorpage.aspx", true);
```

some of the error codes are able to redirect to custom error page. but i am not able to redirect to custom error page if the http code error is 400. it goes the default 400 error page.

**Note**

I don't want to use `IIS` as this is hosted site and I don't have access for it.

is this the right way to do it ?

please let know if I am wrong. and also give me some solution how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

set "customErrors" to "on" in web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error Page/errorpage.aspx"/>
```